# How to correctly extract string in decimal

Tags: php

I can have different element like this inside a string

```
€10.09
69 EUR
69.55$
...
```

I want just the number.
I make that but the `.` isn't taken into consideration

```
  preg_match_all('!\d+!', $price, $matches);
  $out =  (int)implode('', $matches[0]);
```

Result:

```
1009
6955
```

Comment: You need to also match the decimal point: `!\d+(?:\.\d+)?!`.

Comment: You could preg_replace `[\D.]`.

Comment: Please mark the answer which you found most helpful and it solved your query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tk
Finish to find solution
Work fine with these elements

```
  preg_match_all('!\d+!', $price, $matches);
  $price_extracted =  (float)implode('.', $matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this for extracting the values:

```
<?php 
$price = "$10.09,€10.09,69 EUR,69.55$";
  $prices = explode(",",$price);
  foreach($prices as $num){
    preg_match_all('!\d+(\.\d+)?!', $num, $matches);
    $out =  (float)implode('', $matches[0]);
    echo $out." ";
  }
?>
```

Result:

10.09 10.09 69 69.55

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is more complex than most people would bother. while i encourage you to manage to solve it with regular expressions, a practical approach to currency handling in this case would be

```
(float) filter_var( $price, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION ) );
```

this will return the float value, considering decimals

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being "old-skool", but I am all about pointers and I come from a "C"/asm background, in the days where an embedded RTOS system with 512 bytes of stack for each task was a dream come true so...
Here it is, totally optimized for speed. And if only I could do *p++ :) :) :)

```
function extractNumber($s) {
  $started = false;
   $r = "";
  for($i=0; $i<strlen($s); $i++) {
    $c = $s[$i];
    if (($c<'0') && ($c!='.'))
      continue;
    if ($c>'9') {
      if (!$started)
        continue;
      else
        break;
    }
    $started = true;
    $r .= $c;
  }
  return $r;
}
```

The whole run time of this routine will be faster than even THINKING about running a regex. I didn't do it, but if you run some simulations, I can guess mine is at least 500% faster than all the regex/implode/explode solutions proposed.